# How to use session in domain class in grails

Tags: session, grails

I want to store loggedInUser in a table. So i am accessing loggedInUser using session.But i am getting error like no such property session for this class. How to use session in domain?

```
class GenderAudit {


    String name
    User doneBy

    def GenderAudit(Gender gender,String operation)
    {
        this.name=gender.name
        this.doneBy = session.loggedInUser

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Domain classes shouldn't know anything about the HTTP layer. Set the value from a service or controller which has access to that data.

Also, note that defining a constructor like that is fine, but you have to also define a no-arg constructor for Hibernate since it creates new empty instances and calls your setters. In general we don't use parameterized constructors in Grails since the map constructor added by Groovy is so convenient.

Comment: But i have to maintain constructor for this class. I used this RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session As you said  in another post .this is working fine. Thank you so much Burt

Answer (score 2):

Use code in your controllers or services

```
new GenderAudit(name:gender.name, doneBy: session.loggedInUser).save()
```

I'm agree with Burt Beckwith. Remove all constructors from Domain classes.